# Php/SQL/DB2 special characters in where clause

Tags: php, db2

I am trying to SQL a DB2 database (on an iSeries) using PHP and "DB2_exec"- not mysql.

I have these characters in my `WHERE` clause (variable `$EncSSN`) which cause the SQL statement to stop: `ðIn*Éæng` “"Ò×ÑRÈ•`

The SQL is constructed as:

```
select EENUM, EESSN 
from EEMAST 
where EESSN = '$EncSSN'
```

The field in the table EESSN contains encrypted values.
 - I get no errors and no log entries. The html renders a blank page.
 - I have tried replacing (str_replace) quotes, single quotes, period, etc with escape character '\'
 - I can't use mysql_real_escape_string because I am loading the db2_connect resource.

If I change the SQL statement above's `where` to select a value from a different field, my html is rendered properly.

Can you think of anyway I can accomplish this?

Steven

Comment: Before you look any farther - are you sure that your database is setup to handle those characters?  Most legacy tables use [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) encoding, which has a restricted character set.

Comment: The database currently contains thousands of records holding the encrypted values in the EESSN column. I am attempting to retrieve records using the encrypted column as the key

Comment: What does the statement that works look like?  Is the _only_ thing you changed the field reference?

Comment: That is correct, the other statement reads like:select EENUM, EESSN,EEAN8
from EEMAST  
where EEAN8 = 12345 
This displays the record which the SSN record should display. I apprecitate you attempting to assist me. I am frustrated with this task

Comment: Except you just changed the data you are passing to DB2, in addition to the field used for comparison.  What happens if you specify the `EEAN8` field with the same encrypted data?  Do you get a blank page, or do you get an empty result set (assuming they are different)?  Also, check if your DB2 connection includes error handling abilities, and see what information that can provide you with.

Comment: Good suggestion. I replaced the EEAN8 = to be the $EncSSN value. I expect no value returned. Indeed, no record is returned and a blank page (sames as when $EncSSN was used as comparison to EESSN). I have to believe there is a escape issue, however I am not locating the special character causing the SQL to not return anything. I have used db2_escape_string(), str_replace, addslashes(). The value in the DB is ðIn*Éæng “"Ò×ÑRÈ•`

Comment: I can't believe that the DB2 connection library is returning _no_ error codes of any sort (or exceptions).  Turn on debug logging if necessary (if your PHP process is crashing, you should at least get a stack trace).  Also, see @user918176's suggestion about preparing the statment - that may solve this issue (along with making it safer in general).  Oh - can you run the statement on the iSeries itself, or at least not through PHP?  Through a 5250 emulator (command `STRSQL`) or iSeries Navigator?

Comment: I have tried directly on iSeries, however the encrypted characters don't paste quite well in the sql statement, thus I can't do it on the iSeries. As for the prepare statement, I do use prepare and execute.  To clarify as I have continued working on this, I now get past the execute now (no errors), so the issue is in the encrypted characters themselves not being found in the data column with the select clause. There must be a character in the ðIn*Éæng “"Ò×ÑRÈ•` which the DB2 system does not like? I thought the prepare would escape as well? I have seen iSeries like single quote, some  like \

Comment: Yes, the `prepare` should (effectively) escape the data as necessary.  The next bet is to figure out what the database is actually seeing.  Are you able to print out the completed prepared statement (so you can see exactly what will be called)?  Also, can we get the definition of the relevant parts of the table?  And, you already know another key to that row; for testing purposes, if you lookup the encrypted data based on that key, does it match the input (encrypted) value?

Comment: The key value I want to use is 'ðIn*Éæng` “"Ò×ÑRÈ•     the value in the database for SSN when echoed back using a different selection criteria to the same record returns ðIn*Éæng` “"Ò×ÑRÈ•   so it appears as though the SSN key should work. When you say print out prepared statement, you mean the SQL string? If so, it is select YAAN8,YADST from F060116 where YASSN = 'ðIn*Éæng` “"Ò×ÑRÈ•' AND YAPAST='0' for read only. 
What would you need for the table definition? Thanks X-Zero

Comment: The reason I wanted to know about the table definition, was to check if you are using the legacy default of `CCSID 037`.  This doesn't recognize all characters (although it can usually store the bit patterns just fine).  Although, I was able to insert/select the relevant data directly on the iSeries (although this _did_ result in 'different' characters appearing in a couple of places, from what is displayed on my browser).

Comment: The columns in the database F060116 are defined in DDS as CCSID 65535 or blank. What I have to do with some fields that are defined in the DDS as 65535 is within PHP/SQL is cast, such as "cast(YASSN as char(20) CCSID 37).  Our system QCCSID is 65535 and our system QCHRID is 697 37. I have tried casting the YASSN in the "where" clause but that didn't work. Do you think the CCSID may be the culprit?

Comment: Have you tried the cast for this statement?  What happens, in these other places, when you don't specify the casts?  DB2 allows casts around input data, so you only have to perform it the once.  Encoding conversions _may_ be the culprit, but it's good to eliminate it.  Oh, I've been assuming it's a typo, but in your first reply today, the key-value you want to use has a leading apostrophe listed.

Comment: Correct, my copy/paste included a leading apostrophe (sorry). As for the cast, if I do not cast fields with a DDS value of 65535 I get jibberish returned if I echo the data from the column. I have tried casting both the select as well as the where YASSN clauses but still get no hit. BTW, the forum is being polite in asking me to chat instead of lengthening this post. However I can't chat because I am an "8" on this site (i need to be a 10, I think)

Comment: Okay... what happens if you force the cast to `CCSID 037`?  And I haven't been able to store these _exact_ characters in my database - simply pasting them into a session changes them.  Other than that... I get nothing.  Maybe changing the PHP default CCSID, or it's process on the i?  And what is you PHP page encoding, anyways - does changing that help (maybe try UTF-8)?

Comment: Attempting to set it in the `.conf` file as `037` _may_ be setting it to a **hex** value - not at all what you want.  The iSeries doesn't handle the definition of hex values that way, and I've usually just come across that CCSID referenced with a leading 0...

Comment: I changed the .conf file to 37 (removed leading zero) but that didn't change anything unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

[Prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-prepare.php) the SQL and set the parameter for where clause using the array approach. Never ever attempt to build SQL queries by string functions.

Comment: This is especially relevant in a web-facing environment.

Answer (score 0):

try the `addslashes()` function http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

or `heredoc` or `nowdoc` syntax
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

you could also put the sql in a stored proc, but you may have the same issues for the parameter value and need to try one of the above.

Comment: I have tried addslashes, str_replace and db2_escape_string to no avail.